# How can revolving an infinite area have a finite volume

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

The area of the region bounded by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, $y = 0$, and $x = 1$ is

$$
A = \int_1^{+\infty} f(x) \, \textrm{d}x = \lim_{b \to +\infty} \int_1^b \frac{\textrm{d}x}{x} = \lim_{b \to +\infty} [\ln b - \ln 1] = +\infty
$$

The volume of the solid formed by revolving the same region as above is

$$
V = \pi \int_1^{+\infty} [f(x)]^2 \, \textrm{d}x = \lim_{b \to +\infty} \pi \int_1^b \frac{\textrm{d}x}{x^2} = \pi \lim_{b \to +\infty} [-\frac{1}{b} + 1] = \pi
$$

I understand that $y = \frac{1}{x}$ and $y = \frac{1}{x^2}$ are different, so it makes perfect algebraic sense that the area under both curves will be different; one being divergent and the other convergent in this question. But how can it make geometric sense that revolving an infinite area results in a finite volume?

Comment: Why are you not surprised that the area under the line of *infinite length* can be finite? This is the same thing

Comment: @Yuriy S: I've also wondered about this for [many years](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5243599) (decades, in fact). For some reason the one-and-two dimensional version seems to cause MUCH less concern than the two-and-three dimensional version.